# Can you help me find a online resource for gendered handwriting styles, like "ladies' epistolary" and "Mercantile running hand"?

Tags: social-history, resource

Can you help me find a online resource for gendered handwriting styles, like "ladies' epistolary" and "Mercantile running hand"?

Preferably with pictures, as I want an easy reference for their appearances?

This cannot be served by search engines because there is no online resource that has anything close to a comprehensive list of these old handwriting styles of the 18th and 19th centuries.

Searching "ladies' epistolary" and "Mercantile running hand" together gets this question as the top result, and there are only 6 results in Google.

Here: https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22ladies%27+epistolary%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=lBFWVtGhCcLl-AGEpJjgCQ#q=%22ladies%27+epistolary%22+%22Mercantile+running+hand%22

Handwriting in America is the closest thing to a comprehensive source and it only adds Roundhand to the list of writing styles. Plus, it is a scanned Google Book, without pictures of those writing styles.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requests resources/references which could be obtained by research /search engines.

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a history question. Is there a penmanship stack?

Comment: @Semaphore - Sorry... These are historical handwriting styles. The only way to get these now is through happenstance in a person's writing or by following 18-19th century handwriting manuals.